# Salesforce Opportunity Confirmation Warning on Save

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying to get a Yes/Cancel confirmation screen to appear when a user tries to save a opportunity with a "Proposal" stage that asks "Are you sure?"

The route I'm taking is adding a Visualforce page to a standard Opportunity object.  The code I've included launching the confirmation window after it's been saved

Please help!

Error 1 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJmh4.jpg)

Error 2 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfwJY.jpg)

```
   <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" rendered="{!Opportunity.StageName == 'Proposal Request'}">
<script type="text/javascript">
{ window.alert("Are you ready to send a proposal?"); }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Jquery and call the below while loading the page.

```
var htmlhead = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">';
var$g=jQuery.noConflict();$g(function({$g('head').append(htmlhead);$g('head').append('<linkrel="stylesheet"href="yourstaticresources"type="text/css"media="all"/>');$g('body').append('Any dialog box');$g("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: true,buttons: {'{!$Label.Yes}': function() {ifYes();},'{!$Label.No}': function() {$g(this).dialog("close");}}});})} else{ifNo();}}
```

This will open dialog box with `Yes or No`. Handle your logic accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  It looks like it's giving me errors when trying this code in my visualforce page.  Any other ideas on how I can get it to work within SF?

Comment: please share the error. i have added in @salesforce only

Comment: I saved the images in the original message. The first error is a DOCTYPE message, and if I remove that portion, I get the second error.

Comment: Hi @JohnHollins, please add javascript inside <script>,

Comment: <apex:page> 
<script type = "text/javascript"> add code here </script> </apex:page>

Comment: Apologize in advance, I haven't done much with VF pages.  

I'm getting this error - Error: Field $Label.Yes does not exist. Check spelling

Do I need to create a "Yes"/"No" field for it to pull from?  Also, which portion do I add my message.

Appreciate your time in working through this!

Comment: Yes, need to create custom label. otherwise try like below..<apex:page> <script type = "text/javascript"> 
function callOnload() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        ifYes();
    }
    return false;
}
</script>